# how to check all items in my RadListBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

Aspx.cs:

```
RadListDirectionDetail.DataSource = m_listeDirection;    
RadListDirectionDetail.DataValueField = "DepartmentId";    
RadListDirectionDetail.DataTextField = "DepartmentName";    
RadListDirectionDetail.DataBind();    
if (RadListDirectionDetail.Items.Count > 0)    
{    
     for (int i = 0; i < RadListDirectionDetail.Items.Count; i++)    
     {    
          RadListDirectionDetail.Items[i].Checked = false;    
     }    
}
```

Aspx:

```
<telerik:RadAjaxPanel runat="server" ID="RadAjaxPanel2">    
    <telerik:RadListBox ID="RadListDirectionDetail" runat="server" CheckBoxes="true" Width="200px" ShowCheckAll = "true"     
     SelectionMode="Multiple" AutoPostBack="True" Height="55px" Skin="Outlook" Visible="false" Enabled="False">
    </telerik:RadListBox>    
</telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? We don't understand what you want only by looking at your code.

Comment: i'm trying this code and the items are not checked in my interface

Comment: Well if you want them checked why are you setting `Checked = false` instead of `true`?

Comment: even with true its not working

Comment: @DaliBradai well false is definitely wrong. Also, why do you have `Visible=false`? How are you going to see their checked if it's not visible???

Comment: visible = true  by this that there are access rights after I made visible with good accees .
definitely wrong why???

Comment: If you're trying to set something as checked, how can setting Checked = false be correct? You're unchecking it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the Visible and Enabled properties of your RadListBox are both set to False.

Try

```
<telerik:RadListBox ID="RadListDirectionDetail" runat="server" CheckBoxes="true" Width="200px" ShowCheckAll = "true"     
 SelectionMode="Multiple" AutoPostBack="True" Height="55px" Skin="Outlook" Visible="True" Enabled="True">
```

And

```
RadListDirectionDetail.Items[i].Checked = true;
```

Comment: Always the same problem

Comment: @DaliBradai then I suspect the error is elsewhere. Are you sure this code is even being called?

Comment: I'm sure I call this code as the debugger passes through this piece of code with STOP mode point

Answer (score 0):

You want to check all when page load.
You can use the following code

Code In Front

```
<telerik:RadListBox ID="RadListBox1" runat="server" CheckBoxes="true" SelectionMode="Multiple" OnItemDataBound="RadListBox1_ItemDataBound"></telerik:RadListBox>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Check
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Variable
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("departmentID");
        dt.Columns.Add("departmentName");
        Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dic.Add("Dep1", "1");
        dic.Add("Dep2", "2");
        dic.Add("Dep3", "3");
        dic.Add("Dep4", "4");

        // Loop
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> valuepair in dic) dt.Rows.Add(valuepair.Value, valuepair.Key);

        RadListBox1.DataSource = dt;
        RadListBox1.DataTextField = "departmentName";
        RadListBox1.DataValueField = "departmentID";
        RadListBox1.DataBind();


    }
}

protected void RadListBox1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RadListBoxItemEventArgs e)
{
    // Check Count
    if (RadListBox1.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < RadListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            RadListBox1.Items[i].Checked = true;
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you